# Interferance when pairing <input> with DOMs

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```html
<h1 id="ws-title"></h1>
<time datetime="" id="ws-date"></time>
```

JS:

```js
inp1 = document.querySelector("input[name='ws-date']");
out1 = document.querySelector("#ws-date");
inp1.addEventListener("input", e => {
        out1.textContent=e.target.value;
});

inp2 = document.querySelector("input[name='ws-title']");
out2 = document.querySelector("#ws-title");
inp2.addEventListener("input", e => {
        out2.textContent=e.target.value;
});
```

Works as expected (i.e: changing input changes corresponsing h2).

However:

```js
function pairListen(name) {
    inp = document.querySelector(`input[name='${name}']`);
    out = document.querySelector(`#${name}`);
    inp.addEventListener("input", e => {
            out.textContent=e.target.value;
    });
}
pairListen("ws-title");
pairListen("ws-date");
```

Causes `<h2 id="ws-date">` to be changed when `<input name="ws-title">` is changed and vice versa.

Why is that? All difference is that repeated code is embedded in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you declare a variable without a declarator (i.e. `var`, `let`, or `const`) it automatically gets defined in `window`, `this`, and `globalThis` (making those kinds of variables **global**, accessible anywhere in your code). The second time you do `varName = "value";`, you're not redeclaring the variable. You're modifying it. You can solve this by applying a declarator.

```js
function pairListen(name) {
    const inp = document.querySelector(`input[name='${name}']`);
    const out = document.querySelector(`#${name}`);
    inp.addEventListener("input", e => {
            out.textContent=e.target.value;
    });
}
pairListen("ws-title");
pairListen("ws-date");
```

```html
<h1 id="ws-title"></h1>
<input name="ws-title" />
<h2 id="ws-date"></h2>
<input name="ws-date" />
```

Moral of the story—always declare variables with declarators, or you'll encounter unprecedented results. You can force yourself to follow good style by adding `"use strict";` to the top of all your JavaScript files, which will not tolerate writing code that will give you unexpected results.

Comment: 1) That's weird, doesn't javascript destroy variables after the scope ends?. 2) "it automatically gets defined...", as what by default? 3) in this case there is no difference between using any of `var, const, let`, am I correct?

Comment: @AvidSeeker 1: JavaScript destroys variables that have declarators at the end of a function. Variable declarations **without** declarators **immediately becomes globally scoped**, hence defined in window or `globalThis`. 2: It only gets defined if it wasn't defined before and if you're assigning a value to it (default value would be `undefined` or "ReferenceError", depending on how you use it). 3: The main difference is that it's illegal in strict JavaScript, and **most importantly** it gets defined in the global scope, `globalThis`. And yes, that makes it a huge difference.